# how can i pass keys in jenkins script without using binding plugin

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins

How I can put s3 upload credentials to Jenkins file without using a binding plugin. so by that, I mean that the Jenkins pipeline code will be public but credentials should remain private.

I can think of some kind of encrypted keys but I don't know how to deal with them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this for more information.

https://medium.com/@mukeshsingal/access-jenkins-global-environment-variables-using-groovy-or-java-b5c1e6b53685